# Garmin Express and WINE

Tags: wine

I've followed [this website](https://www.christitus.com/garmin-express-linux/) to install Garmin Express on Ubuntu 20.4  everything installs fine with wine and when I run

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/GarminExpress wine explorer /desktop=garmin,1366x768 /home/$USER/Downloads/GarminExpress.exe
```

After downloading the software .exe from Garmins website in my download folder the GUI/WINE launches fine, I agree to terms click install...

```
failed to install Garmin Express
```

I'm wondering what could be wrong here?

Comment: Please do not just share a link. You need to put all issued commands to your question.